# Add multiple colspans that line up in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm building a calendar scheduler where I am hoping to add multiple tasks to one employee row. Whenever I try to add multiple tasks to the same time span, the spans no longer line up. Here is an example of how it looks now: [image: Calendar as of now]. What would be the best practice to add tasks to the same day columns while keeping a task like "Slaughter them" similar?

HTML Script:

```
<script>
                  var sysDate = new Date();
                  var sysDay = new Date();
                  var sysMonth = new Date();
                  var dayCount = sysDay.getDay();
                  var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
                  let employee;
                  let typeofKey;
                  let empArry = [];
                  let x = 1;
                  let y = 0;
                  let trInc= 0;
                  var drawTable = '<table id = wholeTable>';
                  drawTable += "<thead>";
                  drawTable += "<tr>";
                  drawTable += "<th style='color:white;'>Employee Name<\/th>";
                  let today = new Date();
                  let dd = today.getDate();
                  let mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                  let mmN = mm;
                  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                  let oneWeekAhead = new Date();
                  let nextWeek = (today.getDate()+10) + 10;
                                    /* If next week falls into the next month, print correctly */
                  if (nextWeek > 30 && (mmN == 9 || mmN == 4 || mmN == 6 || mmN == 11)) {
                    mmN++;
                    nextWeek -= 30;
                  }
                  else if (nextWeek > 31 && (mmN == 1 || mmN == 3 || mmN == 5 || mmN == 7 || mmN == 8 || mmN == 10 || mmN == 12)) {
                    mmN++;
                    nextWeek -= 31;
                  }
                  else if (nextWeek > 28 && mmN == 2) {
                    mmN++;
                    nextWeek -= 28;
                  }
                                    /* Formatting of the dates at the top of the table */
                  if(dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0'+ dd;
                  }
                  if(nextWeek < 10) {
                    nextWeek = '0' + nextWeek;
                  }
                  if(mmN < 10) {
                      mmN = '0' + mmN
                  }
                  if(mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm;
                  }
                  let edate = yyyy + mmN + nextWeek;
                  /* Finds the logged earliest and latest dates */
                  let startDate1  = yyyy.toString() +  mm.toString() + dd.toString();
                  let startDate = parseInt(startDate1);
                  let endDate = parseInt(edate);
                  let startDateN = 20180501;
                  let endDateN = 20180531;
                                    /* Change the strings of dates to ints for calculation of start and end date of the table */
                  if( localStorage.length > 0){
                  for (var key in localStorage) {
                    typeofKey = (typeof localStorage[key]);
                    if (typeofKey == 'string' || typeofKey instanceof String ){
                      emp1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                      if ("Task" in emp1) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < emp1.Task.length; i++) {
                          startDateN = parseInt(emp1.Task[i]['Task Start Date'].substr(0,4) + emp1.Task[i]['Task Start Date'].substr(5,2) + emp1.Task[i]['Task Start Date'].substr(8,2));
                          endDateN = parseInt(emp1.Task[i]['Task End Date'].substr(0,4) + emp1.Task[i]['Task End Date'].substr(5,2) + emp1.Task[i]['Task End Date'].substr(8,2));
                          if(endDateN > endDate) {
                            endDate = endDateN;
                          }
                          if(startDateN < startDate) {
                            startDate = startDateN;
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                  let numStr = null;
                  let numStrDay = null;
                  let finalDay = null;
                  let finalDayF = null;
                  let colCount = 0;
                                    /* Correctly print the months and days at the top of the table */
                  for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate +1; i++) {
                    numStr = (i.toString()).substr(4,2);
                    numStrDay = (i.toString()).substr(6,2);
                    if(numStr == '09' || numStr == '04' || numStr == '06' || numStr == '11') {
                      if(numStrDay == '31') {
                        i += 69;
                      }
                      else {
                        finalDay = i.toString()
                        finalDayF = (finalDay.substr(0,4)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(4,2)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(6,2));
                        drawTable += "<th class = days id = days" + x + '-' + y + ">" + finalDayF + "</th>";
                        colCount++;
                      }
                    }
                    else if(numStr == '01' || numStr == '03' || numStr == '05' || numStr == '07' || numStr == '08' || numStr == '10' || numStr == '12') {
                      if(numStrDay == '32') {
                        i += 68;
                      }
                      else {
                        finalDay = i.toString()
                        finalDayF = (finalDay.substr(0,4)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(4,2)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(6,2));
                        drawTable += "<th class = days id = days" + x + '-' + y + ">" + finalDayF + "</th>";
                        colCount++;
                      }
                    }
                    else if(numStr == '02') {
                      if(numStrDay == '29') {
                        i += 71;
                      }
                      else {
                        finalDay = i.toString()
                        finalDayF = (finalDay.substr(0,4)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(4,2)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(6,2));
                        drawTable += "<th class = days id = days" + x + '-' + y + ">" + finalDayF + "</th>";
                        colCount++;
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      finalDay = i.toString()
                      finalDayF = (finalDay.substr(0,4)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(4,2)) + "-" + (finalDay.substr(6,2));
                      drawTable += "<th class = days id = days" + x + '-' + y + ">" + finalDayF + "</th>";
                      colCount++;
                    }
                    x++;
                  }
                  drawTable += "</tr>";
                  drawTable += "</thead>";
                  drawTable += '<tbody class="dragscroll">';
                  //drawTable += "<tr id =" + trInc + ">";
                  //trInc++;
                  //counters for the employee and date rows/col
                  x=0;
                  y=1;
                  // counter for the main table
                  let z =1;
                  for (var key in localStorage) {
                    typeofKey = (typeof localStorage[key]);
                    //cols of the employee names
                    if(typeofKey == 'string' || typeofKey instanceof String ){
                                            drawTable += "<tr id =" + trInc + ">";
                          trInc++;
                      employee = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
                      drawTable += "<td class = employ id =emp" + x + '-' + y + ">" + employee['Employee Name'] + "</td>";
                      // rows and cols of the main table and date
                      for (let j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                        drawTable += "<td class =" + z + '-' + y + "></td>";
                        z++;
                      }
                      // set z to one to start the main tables x at 1 for off by one error
                      z=1;
                      //reset x for each row
                      x=0;
                    drawTable += '</tr>';
                    y++;
                  }
                }
               drawTable += '<tr>';
               var noRows = 14 - localStorage.length;
                for(; noRows >= 0; noRows--){
                  drawTable += "<td class = employ id =emp" + x + '-' + y + ">" + "" + "</td>";
                  // rows and cols of the main table and date
                  for (let j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                    drawTable += "<td class =" + z + '-' + y + "></td>";
                    z++;
                  }
                  // set z to one to start the main tables x at 1 for off by one error
                  z=1;
                  //reset x for each row
                  x=0;
                drawTable += '</tr>';
                y++;
                }
                drawTable += "</tbody>";
                drawTable += "</table>";
                document.write(drawTable);
                        </script>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  /* border: 0.0625em solid black; */
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #e1e1e1, #f6f6f6);
}

/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: 1535px;
  overflow: visible;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

td, th {
    padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
    text-align: left;
}

thead th {
  min-width: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) { /*first cell in the header*/
    position: relative;
    display: float;
    min-width: 140px;
    background-color: #202020;
}

/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  width: 1535px;
  height: 475px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
  border: 2px solid #474747;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  /*display: block; seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
}

.dragscroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 600px;
}

.days {
    background-color: #31bc86;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.employ {
        background-color: #2ea879;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
}

#taskDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#days, #emp{
background-color: #071833;
color: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;

}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #071833;

}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #1caf8f
}
```

JS:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  let typeofKey;
  let empArry = [];
  let employee;
  let myTable = document.getElementById('wholeTable');
  let colFill = false;
  let color = null;
        //cols of the employee names
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      empArry.push(localStorage.key(i))
  }
  // loop through the local storage and pull the data
  for(let j = 0; j < empArry.length; j++){
    color = getRandomColor();
    employee = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(empArry[j]));
    // If employee has any task
    if("Task" in employee){
      // while employee has task in his array
      for(let taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < employee.Task.length; taskIndex++){
         for(let k = 1; k < myTable.rows[0].cells.length; k++) {
           if(myTable.rows[0].cells[k].innerHTML == employee.Task[taskIndex]["Task Start Date"]) {
             colFill = true;
           }
           if(colFill == true) {
             myTable.rows[j+1].cells[k].innerHTML += '<div style="background-color:' + color + '">' + employee.Task[taskIndex]["Task Name"] + '</br></div>';
           }
           if(myTable.rows[0].cells[k].innerHTML == employee.Task[taskIndex]["Task End Date"]) {
             colFill = false;
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py5gzw0b/1/#&togetherjs=eM8xgAd5eV

Comment: Adding a new row for each task would not work. An employee could end up having 100+ tasks assigned to them over the course of months. Adding a new row for each task would end up with a lot of unnecessary whitespace on the days before and after the tasks. I am trying to make it to where if two different tasks are assigned to the same person on different day spans, that they will be on the same row.

Comment: Appreciate the javascript, but we will likely need the HTML and CSS too as this is a styling problem

Answer (score 4):

Set the vertical-align CSS property for those table cells to top;

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: This works to a degree, but when I add another task that starts before "Cry to Padme about dead mother" and ends after it for Anakin, then the parts before and after line up with "Cry to Padme about dead mother" instead of the task it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

If you need each item to be on its own row [along with all identical tasks] and perfectly aligned there, then you would need to create row 1, and insert only the Slaughter tasks, followed by creating row 2, inserting only the Cry tasks.  This would then ensure that they would all correctly line up with one another, although it would take up more space as a result.

Comment: I need to make sure that it still lines up with the employee it belongs to. So this would be like adding a row into the Anakin row?

Comment: Correct -- basically, the Anakin row would actually be 2 rows, with the first column for Anakin's name being set as rowspan 2 to fully span across the data.

Comment: And for aesthetic purposes, I could make the borders of those rows hidden so that way it just looks like multiple bars in one row with an extended height?

Comment: Could this also create a problem down the road where if many tasks are added to one employee many months later, a lot of unnecessary rows will be added making it a huge employee cell?

Comment: Yup.  Really just depends on how you wanted to style it, but you could use empty-cells: hide, for instance, to hide the border on all cells that are empty.

Comment: But yes, if you have a lot of tasks on one employee, then you will add a large number of unnecessary rows, as a consequence of having them all line up in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution besides creating a row for each task would be to use jQuery to find the "max top of the task" and setting all instances at that top. Since they take the same space it should be doable and more flexible BUT you're in for some css-positioning fun.

To be more specific, you should :

1/ Add an unique identifier to each task : `<div id_task="1" style=...`

2/ Loop on each instance to find max top value :

```
maxTop=0;
$('[id_task=1]').each(function(){
  newTop=$(this).position().top;
  if(newTop>maxTop)maxTop=newTop;
});
```

3/ Use `maxTop` to set all `id_task=1` to the same top, probably set these divs to relative too : `$('[id_task=1]').css({'top':maxTop,'position':'relative');`

4/ Enjoy fine-tuning this to close in on your desired goal, it'll take a while ^^

I made the code quickly as an example, there's no guarantee to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```js
var cols = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
var employees = [
  {
    Name: 'Jason',
    Task:[
      {'Task Start Date':'Mon','Task End Date':'Thu','Task Name':'Do nothing'},
      {'Task Start Date':'Thu','Task End Date':'Fri','Task Name':'Do a bit'},
      {'Task Start Date':'Sat','Task End Date':'Sun','Task Name':'Do everything'}
    ]
  },
  {
    Name: 'Timmy',
    Task:[
      {'Task Start Date':'Mon','Task End Date':'Sun','Task Name':'On vacation'},
      {'Task Start Date':'Sat','Task End Date':'Sun','Task Name':'Still on vacation'},
    ]
  }
]

function RowCompound(employee,columns){
 var tasks = employee.Task
 var spans = []
  var max_rows = 1
  var rowmap = []
  var rows = []
  
  function calcSpans(){
   for(var i=0;i<tasks.length;i++){
      var cspan = null
      for(var u=0;u<columns.length;u++){
        if(tasks[i]['Task Start Date']==columns[u]){
          cspan = {row:0,start:u,task:tasks[i]}
        }
        if(cspan && tasks[i]['Task End Date']==columns[u]){
          cspan.end = u
          spans.push(cspan)
          cspan = null
        }
      }
      if(cspan){
        cspan.end = columns.length-1
        spans.push(cspan)
      }
    }
  }
  
  function solveConflicts(){
   var conflict = true
    while(conflict){
      conflict = false
      for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
        for(var u=i+1;u<spans.length;u++){
          if(spans[i].row!=spans[u].row) continue
          if(spans[i].start>spans[u].end || spans[i].end<spans[u].start) continue
          conflict = true
          max_rows = Math.max(max_rows,++spans[u].row + 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function createRowMap(){
   for(var u=0;u<max_rows;u++){
      var row = []
      for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
        var empty = true
        for(var k=0;k<spans.length;k++){
          if(spans[k].row!=u) continue
          if(i==spans[k].start){
            empty = false
            var span = spans[k].end-spans[k].start+1
            row.push({task:spans[k].task,colspan:span,rowspan:1})
            i += span-1
            break
          }
        }
        if(empty)
          row.push({task:null,colspan:1,rowspan:1})
      }
      rowmap.push(row)
    }
  }
  
  function buildDom(){
    for(var i=0;i<rowmap.length;i++){
      var row = document.createElement('tr')
      for(var u=0;u<rowmap[i].length;u++){
        if(rowmap[i][u].rowspan==0) continue
        var cell = document.createElement('td')
        cell.colSpan = rowmap[i][u].colspan
        cell.rowSpan = rowmap[i][u].rowspan
        if(rowmap[i][u].task){
          cell.innerHTML = rowmap[i][u].task['Task Name']
          cell.className = 'busy'
        }
        row.appendChild(cell)
      }
      rows.push(row)
    }
    
    var head = document.createElement('td')
    head.rowSpan = max_rows
    head.innerHTML = employee.Name
    rows[0].prepend(head)
  }
  
  calcSpans()
  solveConflicts()
  createRowMap()
  buildDom()
  
  return rows
}


// example use
employees.forEach(function (emp){
 var result_rows = RowCompound(emp,cols)
  for(var i in result_rows){
    document.getElementById('table').appendChild(result_rows[i])
  }
})
```

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 50px;
}
table td.busy{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Sun</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

What this does is:

- Create virtual spans for each task
- If the spans overlap, push them one row lower
- Create multiple rows utilizing the `rowSpan` attribute
- Append the said rows to the table

You're gonna need to rewrite your code a little for this to work, but i think its the way to go.
Please note, the `createRowCompound` function requires the columns of the table as array in order to create the layout. See the example use.

Questions?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a conceptual answer/idea, but I think that you might be able to use the Isotope javascript layout library with the "vertical" layout mode:

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

You can disable all kinds of animations, so in that sense, this would be a shortcut to the "css positioning fun" that @Nomis mentions in the answer above. There's also the https://masonry.desandro.com library by the same person - might be worth a look.